# Exact definition of regular pyramid

Tags: solid-geometry

I need a complete definition of **regular pyramid**
, ie, when we can called some  pyramid  "a regular pyramid"?
Is is about it's base only? Or it also about the apex of pyramid?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base is a regular polygon and a foot of the altitude it's the center of the circumcircle of the base.

Comment: you mean that we must have 2 conditions: first ,regular base;  second : altitude is passing through the centroid of base , am I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes. This is exactly, which I mean.